# End of script output before headers during file upload

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

This is what was returned by Apache when uploading files above `200MB`.

> End of script output before headers during file upload

It takes about 10 minutes to upload that file.
Any other files below that size seems to be alright.

The files are uploaded by chunks.

I've already set the max_execution_time to be 3000, but the problem still persists.

Updated:
The file gets uploaded into the directory but the server response from the Ajax seems to be returning a new page request response rather than a specific JSON string from the file upload request.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Apache's `LimitRequestBody` directive at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` with the desired limit, expressed in bytes:

```
LimitRequestBody 209715200
```

209715200 = 200Mb

Comment: I forgot to mention, the file is actually successfully uploaded to the directory. but the request response from the server seems creating a new request instead of returning proper response. And since it's an Ajax process and expecting a specific JSON, the database doesn't get updated.

Comment: Put these additional information on your question, as an edit.